# default argument in bound function

Tags: python

I'm developing a python script which sends text data to a zebra labelprinter.
There's one bound function called "zebra_line" and you have to fill in x, y, text and font variables.

```
    zebra_line = "^FO{x},{y}^A0,N,{font}^FH^FD{text}^FS".format

    template = "^XA\n"
    template += "^CI28\n"
    template += zebra_line(x=30,y=350, text="Test", font=35)
    template += zebra_line(x=30,y=700, text="Test", font=35)

send_to_printer(template)
```

This works nice but my problem is with the font argument. I don't want to pass it with every line as it is mostly the same.

So...is it possible to use default arguments in bound functions in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "bound functions"?  Bound methods can have default arguments like any other functions, but default argument values are part of the function's *definition*, not part of the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, however, not with an existing function. You can write a wrapper function, or you could use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and supply a default argument for `font`:

```
from functools import partial

zebra_line = partial("^FO{x},{y}^A0,N,{font}^FH^FD{text}^FS".format, font=35)
```

Now the default value of 35 will be used if the `font` keyword argument is not supplied:

```
>>> print(zebra_line(x=30,y=350, text="Test"))
^FO30,350^A0,N,35^FH^FDTest^FS
>>> print(zebra_line(x=30,y=350, text="Test", font=1234))
^FO30,350^A0,N,1234^FH^FDTest^FS
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here is the code that would do this for you:

```
from functools import partial

zebra_line = partial(zebra_line, font=35)
```

Now, you can call `zebra_line` like this:

```
zebra_line(x=30,y=700, text="Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define your own wrapper function.

(not sure if there'll be a conflict with the named parameters and the function parameters, but you get the idea)

```
def my_zebra_line(x, y, text):
    zebra_line(x=x,y=y, text=text, font=35)

template += my_zebra_line(30,700, "Test")
```

Though, I'm not sure why this wouldn't work (remove the font as a parameter)

```
zebra_line = "^FO{x},{y}^A0,N,35^FH^FD{text}^FS".format
```